# Pandas dataframe Plotly line chart with two lines

Tags: python, pandas, graph, charts, plotly

I have a pandas dataframe as below and I would like to produce a few charts with the data. 'Name' column are the names of the accounts, 'Number' column is the number of users under each count, and the months columns are the login times of each account in every month.

```
Acc       User     Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     June
Nora      39       5       13      16      22      14      20
Bianca    53       14      31      22      21      20      29
Anna      65       30      17      18      28      12      13
Katie     46       9       12      30      34      25      15
Melissa   29       29      12      30      10      4       9
```

1st: I would like to monitor the trend of logins from January to May. One line illustrates Bianca's login and the other line illustrates everyone else's login.

2nd: I would like to monitor the percentage change of logins from January to May. One line illustrates Bianca's login percentage change and the other line illustrates everyone else's login percentage change.

Thank you for your time and assistance. I'm a beginner at this. I appreciate any help on this! Much appreciated!!

Comment: First of all try to manipulate you dataframe to get the wanted values as Lists, pandas Series etc. (→ things like df.sum() and df.pct_change() should do the job. Than have a look at [Line charts using plotly](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#:~:text=Line%20Plot%20with%20plotly.,-express&text=Plotly%20Express%20is%20the%20easy,polyline%20mark%20in%202D%20space.) to get the desired visualization.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest best approach to group is use categoricals.  pct_change is not a direct aggregate function so it's a bit more involved to get it.

```
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Acc       User     Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     June
Nora      39       5       13      16      22      14      20
Bianca    53       14      31      22      21      20      29
Anna      65       30      17      18      28      12      13
Katie     46       9       12      30      34      25      15
Melissa   29       29      12      30      10      4       9"""), sep="\s+")

# just setup 2 plot areas
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=[20,5])

# want to divide data into 2 groups
df["grp"] = pd.Categorical(df["Acc"], ["Bianca","Others"])
df["grp"].fillna("Others", inplace=True)
# just get it out of the way...
df.drop(columns="User", inplace=True)
# simple plot where function exists directly.  Not transform to get lines..
df.groupby("grp").sum().T.plot(ax=ax[0])
# a bit more sophisticated to get pct change...
df.groupby("grp").sum().T.assign(
         Bianca=lambda x: x["Bianca"].pct_change().fillna(0)*100,
         Others=lambda x: x["Others"].pct_change().fillna(0)*100
     ).plot(ax=ax[1])
```

**output**
[image]